# Swift Navigation Bar Title appears black instead of white

Tags: swift

Since the introduction of dark modes the bar title of my main UIViewController appears black instead of white by default. When I set mode to dark in my settings, the title appears in white. But I don´t want to switch modes, I simply want my title to appear in white color by default.

I´ve tried to set the title color explicitly to white but none of the options below (tintColor or titleTextAttributes) worked.
Any ideas?

```
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 98.0/255, green: 194.0/255, blue: 208.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationItem.title = "Title"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set UInavigationController colors in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function at **AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)


    let navBarAppearnce = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navBarAppearnce.barTintColor = .white
    navBarAppearnce.tintColor = .black
    navBarAppearnce.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]

    //other stuff
    return true
}
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for,